# How to use the substitution rule for indefinite integrals to obtain the following result?

Tags: calculus, integration

My book claims the following: $$ x = f(t) $$ $$y = g(t)$$

then, by substitution rule $$ \int y \ dx = \int g(t)f'(t) \ dt$$

I cannot find a way to obtain this result. Could someone show all the steps to obtain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x = f(t)$, then $\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{df(t)}{dt} = f'(t)$, so $dx = f'(t)dt$. Alternatively, one can immediately obtain $dx = f'(t)dt$ by chain rule.

The rest is simply substituting $g(t)$ where you see $y$ and $f'(t)dt$ where you see $dx$.

Comment: How can you multiply both sides of $\frac {dx}{dt} = f'(t)$ by dt? I thought it was just a notation for derivative.

Comment: Perhaps this question (and answer by Arturo Magidin) might be of use. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/is-dy-dx-not-a-ratio/21209#21209

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this down.
We have:
$$ x = f(t) $$ $$y = g(t)$$ 
And we're looking to express in terms of those functions the following integral:$$ \int y \ dx$$ 
Let's substitute only $y$ to begin with. So the integral becomes:
$$\int g(t)dx$$

Now let's look at substituting the $dx$ and rearranging.

If $x=f(t)$, then $\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{df(t)}{dt}.$
$i.e.  \frac{dx}{dt} = f'(t).$
$\therefore  {dx} = f'(t)dt.$

Now to complete the substitution, substitute $dx$ with our result:
$$\int g(t)dx = \int g(t)f'(t)dt$$